# a4j:commandLink action dont work but i replace with h:commandLink work if i click two times

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-2.2

JSF 2.2 and RichFaces 4

i have three pages, the first have a rich:dataTable with names of people, click on that names and take me to the second page which have info about that person and two rich:dataTable, the last dataTable have in the first column a a4j:commandLink which send me to the third. The problem is in the last a4j:commandLink it not fired the action method and if i replace with h:commandLink work but with two click on it.

the code:

FIRST PAGE

```
<h:form>
    <rich:dataTable value="#{listadoClienteBacking.listadoGeneralDeCliente}" var="cli">
        <f:facet name="header">LISTADO DE TODOS LOS CLIENTES</f:facet>
        <rich:column>
            <f:facet name="header">NOMBRE DE CLIENTE</f:facet>
            <a4j:commandLink value="#{cli.nombre}" action="#{listadoClienteBacking.consultaCliente(cli.cedula)}"/>
        </rich:column>
        <rich:column>
            <f:facet name="header">EMPRESA</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{cli.empresa}"/>
        </rich:column>
        <rich:column>
            <f:facet name="header">VALOR PROXIMA CUOTA</f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{cli.valor}">
                <f:convertNumber pattern="#,##0"/>
            </h:outputText>
        </rich:column>
    </rich:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

SECOND PAGE

```
<h:form>
    //info on input
    <rich:dataTable value="#{listadoClienteBacking.listActCli}" var="act_cli" iterationStatusVar="it">
        //column with information about this people
    </rich:dataTable>
    <rich:dataTable value="#{listadoClienteBacking.listPrestCli}" var="pp" iterationStatusVar="it2">
        <rich:column>
            <f:facet name="header">NO. PRESTAMO</f:facet>
                <a4j:commandLink value="#{pp.idprestamo}" action="#{listadoClienteBacking.consultaPrestamo(pp.idprestamo)}"/>
        </rich:column>
        //other columns
    </rich:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

THE BACKING

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ListadoClienteBacking{
    private Cliente objCliente = new Cliente();
    private List<DataTableCliente> listadoGeneralDeCliente = new ArrayList<DataTableCliente>();
    private List<Actividad_cliente> listActCli = new ArrayList<Actividad_cliente>();
    private List<DataTablePrestamo> listPrestCli = new ArrayList<DataTablePrestamo>();
    //construct, getter and setter
    public void inicio(){ //this run at the beginin PostConstruct
        ClienteManejador clienteManejador = new ClienteManejador();
        setListadoGeneralDeCliente(clienteManejador.listaResumenCliente());
    } //this fill the first page's info

    public String consultaCliente(String idcliente){
        ClienteManejador clienteManejador = new ClienteManejador();
        PrestamoManejador prestamoManejador = new PrestamoManejador();
        setObjCliente(clienteManejador.buscarCliente(idcliente));
        listActCli.clear();
        setListActCli(clienteManejador.buscarActCli(objCliente));
        listPrestCli.clear();
        setListPrestCli(prestamoManejador.listaResumenPrestamo(idcliente));
        return "cliente";
    } //this fill the second page's info called cliente.xhtml

    public String consultaPrestamo(int idprestamo){
        //do staff
        return "/prestamo/datosPrestamo";
    } //this should take me to the third page but don't
}
```

prestamoManejador, clienteManejador are POJO's and work fine i have verified with the debbuger.

Comment: i found the answer, apparently for some reason can't mix a4j:commandLink with h:commandLink, i change all link component to h:commandLink and work fine.

Comment: please add `execute=@this` to `a4j:commandLink` and give it another try.